# Grails WAR not displaying views

Tags: tomcat, grails, dependencies, grails-plugin, gsp

I am having an issue with Grails 2.2.3 where the Spring Security added login/auth.gsp view is not displaying in the browser when I run `grails run-war` or `grails war` then deploy to a Tomcat server. However it displays and works just fine when I do `grails run-app` or `grails prod run-app`. I have done a `grails clean` several times, as well as recompiled and refreshed dependencies.

A couple of things to note:

- My `login/auth.gsp` view is in a custom UI plugin I am using. It is in
  the projects `BuildConfig.groovy` file as an inplace plugin.
- My `main.gsp` template is also in that custom UI plugin.

The browser returns an HTTP 404:

```
type Status report

message /processes/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/login/auth.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Does anyone know what this issue might be, or how I could fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly and am not completely wrong we had exactly the same problem with our project at work.

The problem was (and it is probably the same for you) that we had two versions set for the plugin.

One was set in **application.properties**

```
app.version=0.1
```

and than there was one set in the **plugin descriptor**

```
def version = "0.1"
```

If you remove the version declaration from the application.properties it should work. The version for plugins is set via plugin descriptor and for projects it's set via application.properties. I don't know how we ended up with the two version declarations but I'm guessing it's either due to some copy and paste mistake or that Grails used to generate plugins' application.properties with `app.version`.

Comment: I took a look at the plugin and the only thing in application.properties is `app.grails.version` and `app.name`. In my plugin descriptor class I have the version declared as `def version = "0.1"`.

Comment: OK. It sounded exactly like the problem we had. We have our views in a plugin and received 404 after changing the version. The views actually existed inside the war file but they were in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 1):

This drove me nuts for several days even after reading this thread.

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 and I have several plugins that come from a vendor which I pull from a git repo.  I recently upgraded a few plugins by getting newer versions from git and encountered this problem.  It seems that when you run `grails war` it builds the plugins and creates a plugin.xml file in the root of each plugin.  The metadata in plugin.xml contains the plugin version (apparently acquired from the xxxGrailsPlugin.groovy file).  The version from plugin.xml is used in naming the folder where the plugin code is stored in the war.  The problem comes in when you change the plugin version since it seems that Grails does not regenerate the plugin.xml file.  `grails clean` does NOT do the trick.  This causes the new version of the plugin to be stored in the war with the old version as part of its folder name.

Once I went through the plugins and removed all plugin.xml files I could successfully rebuild by war deploy it on Tomcat and not get 404's.

Comment: I had the same issue with 2.3.5 - `plugin.xml` version did not match the version number in the descriptor file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use plugins to serve resources, you need to add the `plugin` property. This property is available in most of Grails tags / methods. Consider a plugin called my-plugin.

To use a resource:

```
g.resource(dir: "js", file:"myPluginJs.js", plugin: "myPlugin")
```

To render a plugin view:

```
render(view: 'path/to/view', plugin: "myPlugin")
```

That's also true when you declare a plugin resources file.

```
modules = {
  "my-plugin-module" {
    resource url: '/js/app.js', plugin: 'myPlugin'
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Sérgio. I added `plugin: "myPlugin"` to the Login Controller's `auth` closure then ran `grails prod run-war` again, and I am getting the same result. I did a clean beforehand as well.

Comment: Just to clarify, I added it to the render method so that it was   `render view: 'auth', plugin: 'myPlugin', model: [postUrl: postUrl, rememberMeParameter: config.rememberMe.parameter]`

Comment: Whats the name of your plugin? Please, show me the name of your plugin descriptor class.

Comment: The plugin is called mssu-ui and the plugin descriptor class is `MssuUiGrailsPlugin`.

Comment: So it should be the camel case version: `plugin: 'mssuUi'`.

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" it but I am at a complete loss as to why this worked.

I remembered that I had bumped the version of my inplace plugin from '0.1' to '1.0'. Since doing that, the app has not worked when I build a war. Changing the plugin version back from 1.0 to 0.1 has fixed the issue.

Can anyone explain why this worked? I've cleaned and recompiled the UI plugin as well, but that never worked until I bumped the version back down.

Comment: When you change something in your plugin you need to change the version. You can increment the version, 1.1 will work too. If you don't do that, your application still use the old compiled version.